# Getting a null pointer exception in WebView on loading a webpage with embedded video

Tags: android, html, webview

I am opening a webpage in WebView. The webpage contains an iframe which has an embedded video in it. I cannot post the webpage link, so posting its code.

Code of webpage:

```
<html> 
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"  media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<body>
<div id="here">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
<iframe id="video" class="class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/129955969?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=f2f2ea&amp;autoplay=1" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div
<p style="color:#167AD0;"><a href="#" >Algebra - Progressions</a></p>
<p style="color:#7E8394;">Bulls Eye Knowledge (P) Ltd.<br/>2 months ago * 1 views<br/></p>
<p style="border-top: 1px solid #7e8394;color: #7e8394;margin: 10px 0 0;padding: 0;"></p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Android activity code:

```
public class WebPlayerActivity extends Activity {

public static final String INTENT_EXTRA = "intent_extra";
public static final String INTENT_EXTRA_TITLE = "intent_extra_title";

private WebView webView;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        webView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11)
        webView.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
    TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.back);
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    title.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_TITLE));
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webView.loadUrl(getIntent().getStringExtra(INTENT_EXTRA));
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
}
}
```

The view opens fine at the beginning, but when I click on play, sometimes it gives me the following crash in my samsung tablet (Android version: 4.2.2), and sometimes the audio is running fine, but the video is not getting displayed, only black screen.

Crash:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoView.reprepareData(HTML5VideoView.java:346)
   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy$VideoPlayer.play(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:245)
   at android.webkit.HTML5VideoViewProxy.handleMessage(HTML5VideoViewProxy.java:447)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

Any ideas? I also have android:hardwareAccelerated="true" in my application tag in manifest.

P.S. working fine in my nexus 5 and motorola device with lollipop version.